# C# Generic Type Inheritence

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, system.reflection

Is it possible to create a generic `class<T>` which the generic type `T` will be the `base class` of it?

i.e:

```
MyClass<Base1> b1 = new MyClass<Base1>();
MyClass<Base2> b2 = new MyClass<Base2>();

b1.Name="test";
b2.ID=1;
```

**Base Classes:**

```
class Base1
{
   protected string Name{ get; set;}
}

class Base2
{
   protected int ID{ get; set;}
}
```

**Inherited Class:**

```
class MyClass<T>:T //here is the question is it possible dynamic inheritence
{

}
```

Comment: The answer to `is it possible` is usually "why don't you try it yourself"?

Comment: no, but you can use composition instead

Comment: Of course I already tried before (: My purpose was adding a few property into a library classes which is not belong me. i.e: Adding UIAutomationID property into Button, Picker, Label, TextBox, but also I want to use their own properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a constraint on `T` thus forcing `T` to be of type baseclass, like this:

```
public class baseclass
{
    // base class code
}

// perfectly valid
public class derived1<T> : baseclass where T : baseclass
{
    // derived class code
}
```

It's impossible to compile the following code, since `T` is a type parameter, and the compiler must infer it from usage. obviously that can't be done like this.

```
public class derived2<T> : T
{
    // derived class code
}
```